# CSS и Z-Index

Tags: css3

Почему неправильно работает z-index?
http://jsbin.com/ukahis/1

Comment: Потрясающий вопрос! А как должно быть? Что вообще хотели сделать? Ексель моксель. Тут не все могут читать мысли!

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить - там span внутри стилей другого элемента. И он игнорируется полностью. Если только  Вы не используете что то типа SCSS

Comment: внимательнее, забыл в CSS title закрыть -> }

Comment: @zhenyab тот кто умеет читать код, тот поймет то про что идет речь 
да там less и там ничего не игнорируется 
по идее титл должен был перекрыть спан http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_35kb.1374093955.png

Comment: @ananas222 мне добавить нечего!

Comment: @zhenyab давайте вынесите спан за пределы h1 (не дабавляя других элементов) и сделайте так чтобы его ширина на 120% была больше контента h1 все зависимости от того какой дины там строка

Answer (score 2):

`Z-index` работает правильно. Дело в том, что z-index'ы выставлены родительскому и дочернему элементам. В итоге у дочернего элемента `z-index: 200`, и он перекрывает все содержимое родительского (`z-index` родительского  в `999999` здесь *никак не влияет*).
Если хотите, чтобы дочерний `span` стал "ниже" своего родителя, поставьте ему отрицательный `z-index`.

Comment: все равно http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_32kb.1374094034.png

Comment: Не все равно. Поменяйте цвета и увидите